# Geolocation column and address lookup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, google-maps

I would like to setup a SharePoint 2013 List that has a column called Address to plot a pin marker on a map. The key requirements is that I do not have latitude/longitude information but only address information, e.g. 1 fake st, suburb

It seems like there are two methods of getting this to work: 1. Geolocation Column or 2. Custom Google Maps option.

Which method is the best?

(from what I read, it seems that the Geolocation column only works on lat/longt and not by address lookup)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, geolocation field works only with coordinates. So if you have an address, you need a custom solutions.
One of the simplest way would be to use JSLink with CSR, that would render a link to Google Maps or Bing Maps with the address query string specified. Or you can add a frame with a map in it.

[Here](https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/url-parameters-for-the-bing-maps-website/) is an article how to format Bing Map query

[Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) is CSR samples that could help you

Answer (score 0):

An alternativ option could be to add a Flow to your list doing a web service call to a coordinate to address service and based on the json respons update the address fields on the list

The reverse, getting the coordinates from the address is also an option, at least using the bing api

https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/ff701715.aspx